# Why isn't there a standard way to format a date object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I have a javascript date object and want to format it like this

```
2014-12-18
```

like `%Y-%m-%d` but I can't seem to find a "good way to achieving this at once. Why does javascript not have a strftime function? How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 8):

No need to use an external library:

```
var now = new Date();
var s = now.getFullYear() + '-' + (now.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + now.getDate();
alert(s); // 2014-12-18
```

Explanation:

`getFullYear()` gives you the 4-digit year

`getMonth()` gives you the month (0-based, that's why you have to add 1)

`getDate()` gives you the day of month

Comment: Be aware that getMonth and getDate can be 1-digit so you'll need to optionally pad it with a '0' if you want dates like 2014-01-09 instead of 2014-1-9

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Moment.js ?

[moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Install

```
bower install moment --save # bower
npm install moment --save   # npm
Install-Package Moment.js   # NuGet
```

Format Dates

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // December 18th 2014, 2:08:59 pm
moment().format('dddd');                    // Thursday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Dec 18th 14
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2014 escaped 2014
moment().format();                          // 2014-12-18T14:08:59+01:00
```

Here is the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I gave directly the link because in the official website there is everything you need about moment.js, but i agree with you it's better to give answer here ;)

Comment: FYI moment is a pretty large dependency. There are newer lighter alternatives like https://date-fns.org/ or https://github.com/moment/luxon

Answer (score 1):

You can use library [`moment`](http://momentjs.com/). There is no good reason behind lack of Date formatting functions.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1056730/2446102) contains code to format date as `%Y-%m-%d` in vanilla JS.

Answer (score 1):

Based on helpermethod's answer, here is a way to do it with 0-padded months and dates:

```
function pad(num) {
  return (num >= 10 ? '' : '0') + num;
}

const now = new Date();
const s = now.getFullYear() + '-' + pad(now.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + pad(now.getDate());
alert(s); // 2020-04-08
```

Comment: Simple and efficient, also taking account of values lower than 10 with the padding, I like it. Thanks